# Rename multiple levels of a factor, all of which contain the same word

Tags: r, regex

For example:

```
x1 <- data.frame("ID" = c(1:6), 
                  "Position" = c("Left-Striker", 
                                 "Goalkeeper", 
                                 "Right-Striker",
                                 "Striker",
                                 "Centerback",
                                 "Right-Midfield"))
```

returns:

```
      ID       Position
   1  1    Left-Striker
   2  2      Goalkeeper
   3  3   Right-Striker
   4  4         Striker
   5  5      Centerback
   6  6  Right-Midfield
```

I would like to rename all factors with the word "Striker" inside the factor to "Striker" as the factor name. So the data frame looks like:

```
      ID       Position
   1  1         Striker
   2  2      Goalkeeper
   3  3         Striker
   4  4         Striker
   5  5      Centerback
   6  6  Right-Midfield
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This keeps the variable stored as factor and removes the unused levels, in base `R` :

```
x1$Position[grepl("Striker",x1$Position)] <- "Striker"
x1$Position <- droplevels(x1$Position)
x1$Position
# [1] Striker        Goalkeeper     Striker        Striker        Centerback     Right-Midfield
# Levels: Centerback Goalkeeper Right-Midfield Striker
```

You could also do the following for a similar effect (levels might be sorted differently) :

```
levels(x1$Position)[grepl("Striker",levels(x1$Position))] <- "Striker"
x1$Position
# [1] Striker        Goalkeeper     Striker        Striker        Centerback     Right-Midfield
# Levels: Centerback Goalkeeper Striker Right-Midfield
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I did not have a factor called "Striker" to begin with?

Comment: In this case you could start with `levels(x1$Position) <- c(levels(x1$Position),"Striker")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` we can remove the first word using

```
x1$Position <- gsub('(^\\w+-)(Striker)','\\2',x1$Position)
```

`()` used to group expressions

`(^\\w+-)` first group search for one or more word followed with a `-`

`(Striker)` seconed group search for a literal `Striker`.

`\\2` means discard the first group and return the second group which is `Striker`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do the "(^\\w+-)" and "\\2" mean? Or what do I need to google to understand them?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with the [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) package:

```
forcats::fct_collapse(x1$Position, "Striker" = c("Left-Striker", "Striker", "Right-Striker"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex

```
library(stringr)

x1$Position <- str_replace_all(x1$Position, "[:alpha:]+-?Striker", "Striker")
```

From [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)

> There are a number of pre-built classes that you can use inside []:
>
> > - [:alpha:]: letters.

The `+` means one or more. The `-` is in your string.

Comment: Please could you explain what [:alpha:]+-? means? Or what I can google to search for understanding?